# Is static typing enforced at compile-time or run-time?

Tags: java, c++, language-agnostic, type-systems

Mostly asking about java/c++ with which I'm mainly familiar.

- Is the type information used to check correctness only at compile time and then discarded? (ie. does java work like python after compilation?)
- Is the type information kept and used again for checking during runtime?
- Does this behavior differ among languages

Comment: point three can be answered with Yes, and that makes points 1 and 2 kinda messy.

Comment: @user4581301: thanks. I suspected so, just wanted some example of enforcing or not enforcing types at runtime

Comment: C++'s goal is to get as much out as possible at compile time, so unless you ask for run-time typing, it's gone, with the variables reduced to reduced to offsets in memory. Unless polymorphism is involved asking for `typeid` in the program is almost certainly replaced at compile-time with the correct type information. Java I don't know nearly well enough anymore (and assuming I ever did is risky) to comment on.

Comment: `example of enforcing or not enforcing types at runtime` See: [Hindley–Milner (HM) type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system)

Comment: `thanks.` I don't know if thanks is the right word. If you dig into it, it will be more like `agony and ecstasy`

Comment: @GuyCoder: I suppose so. It produces the best static inference system I have seen.

Comment: If you really like to learn more about type systems ([examples](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9548/%ce%bb-calculus-extensions-meaning-of-extension-symbols)) then get "[Types and Programming Languages](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/)" ([WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/title/types-and-programming-languages/oclc/51958338&referer=brief_results)) by Benjamin C. Pierce.

Comment: Of interest: [Software Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu)

Answer (score 1):

In Java, some type information is kept at runtime.  This is why you can get `java.lang.ClassCastException`s.  Not all of it is, though.  In particular, Generics in Java are implemented using type erasure, meaning that, at runtime, a `ArrayList<String>` looks like a `ArrayList<Integer>` (it won't look like a `HashSet<String>`, though).

In other languages the behavior differs.  In C, for instance, you can do all sorts of things at runtime (e.g. copy a pointer to a string into a variable containing a pointer to an array of integers) without errors, despite the static typing.

Comment: @user4581301 Edited

Answer (score 1):

Types in C++ are for the compiler and are compile time. Templates are *not* generics, they are actually instructions for the compiler to generate static type-specific code. For instance, you can call a static method of a template argument, which is syntactically impossible in Java.

C++ runtime type information is available via [typeid/typeinfo](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/typeinfo), and via the [dynamic_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) operator (the latter may use the former). But even this can be disabled during the compilation to save space.